# Handle limit data with 2 buttons (Next and previous button ) in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

In my work, the concept look like have lot of data in array , but the first one i want to show only 4 object (id 1 to id 4) in array. So , next i press next button that i want to loop the next object in array (id 5 to id 8) , then i press the back button they return to previous object that i pass them . i don't know the logic for this.

```html
<template>
  <v-container fluid>
    <v-row no-gutters>
      <v-col cols="12" md="12" sm="12">
        <v-card>
          <v-row no-gutters>
            <v-col cols="12" md="12" sm="12" class="">
              <v-row no-gutters class="d-flex">
                <v-col
                  cols="6"
                  md="6"
                  v-for="(item, index) in content"
                  :key="`item-${index}`"
                >
                  <v-col cols="6">
                    <v-card-text>
                      <p>{{ item.id }}</p>
                      <p>my name is : {{ item.title }}</p>
                    </v-card-text></v-col
                  >
                </v-col>
              </v-row>
            </v-col>
          </v-row>

          <v-col cols="12" md="12" sm="12" class="d-flex">
            <v-col cols="6" md="6" sm="6">
              <v-btn medium elevation="" color="primary" @click="backpage()"
                >Back</v-btn
              >
            </v-col>
            <v-col cols="6" md="6" sm="6">
              <v-btn medium elevation="" color="primary" @click="nextPage()"
                >Next</v-btn
              >
            </v-col>
          </v-col>
        </v-card>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({
    showCounted: 4,
    content: '',
    nextValue: Number,
    user: [
      {
        id: 1,
        title: 'Saysana',
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        title: 'Binh',
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        title: 'Say',
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        title: 'Q',
      },
      {
        id: 5,
        title: 'a',
      },
      {
        id: 6,
        title: 'b',
      },
      {
        id: 7,
        title: 'c',
      },
      {
        id: 8,
        title: 'e',
      },
      {
        id: 9,
        title: 'e',
      },
      {
        id: 10,
        title: 'e',
      },
      {
        id: 11,
        title: 'e',
      },
      {
        id: 12,
        title: 'e',
      },
    ],
  }),
  computed: {
    defaultPage() {
      return (this.content = this.user.slice(0, this.showCounted))
    },
  },

  methods: {
    async nextPage() {
      this.content = this.user.slice(this.showCounted, this.showCounted + 4)
      console.log(this.content)
      this.showCounted = this.showCounted + 4
    },
    defaultData() {
      this.content = this.user.slice(0, this.showCounted)
    },
    async backpage() {
      const previous = -this.showCounted - 4
      let to = 4
      this.content = this.user.slice(previous, to)
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.defaultData()
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: Several things are wrong here. You should not use the `index` of a `v-for` while looping. A `computed` should not have side effects, make the same change in `mounted` actually. Then, your logic is a bit strange, try to use 2 points for your pagination. The first one, is either 0 or `x`, `x` being the page `times the amount of elements you want to display`. Then, the ending point should be `y` which is `x + the amount of elements you want to display`. Also, please use ESlint to double-check any possible issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like following snippet:
Add data property `currentPage: 1`, then in next/back page increment/decrement current page and `slice(this.showCounted * this.currentPage, this.showCounted * this.currentPage + this.showCounted)` / `slice(this.showCounted * this.currentPage - this.showCounted, this.showCounted * this.currentPage)`. Also you can disable/enable buttons if you are on last/first page. This way you can chose whatever number of items you want to show just set `showCounted` to desired value.

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.config.devtools = false
new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data(){
    return {
      showCounted: 4,
      currentPage: 1,
      content: '',
      nextValue: Number,
      user: [
        {id: 1, title: 'Saysana'}, {id: 2,title: 'Binh'}, {id: 3, title: 'Say'}, 
        {id: 4, title: 'Q'}, {id: 5, title: 'a'}, {id: 6, title: 'b'},
        {id: 7, title: 'c'}, {id: 8, title: 'e'}, {id: 9, title: 'e'}, 
        {id: 10, title: 'e'}, {id: 11, title: 'e'},{id: 12, title: 'e'},
      ],
      isDisabledN: false,
      isDisabledB: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    defaultData() {
      this.content = this.user.slice(0, this.showCounted)
    },
    nextPage() {
      this.content = this.user.slice(this.showCounted * this.currentPage, this.showCounted * this.currentPage + this.showCounted)
      this.currentPage++
      this.checkPage()
    },
    backpage() {
      this.currentPage--
      this.content = this.user.slice(this.showCounted * this.currentPage - this.showCounted, this.showCounted * this.currentPage)
      this.checkPage()
    },
    checkPage() {
      if (this.showCounted  * this.currentPage >= this.user.length) {
        this.isDisabledN = true
        this.isDisabledB = false
      } else if(this.currentPage <= 1) {
        this.isDisabledN = false
        this.isDisabledB = true
      } else {
        this.isDisabledN = false
        this.isDisabledB = false
      }
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.defaultData()
    this.checkPage()
  },
})
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <v-container fluid>
        <v-row no-gutters>
          <v-col cols="12" md="12" sm="12">
            <v-card>
              <v-row no-gutters>
                <v-col cols="12" md="12" sm="12" class="">
                  <v-row no-gutters class="d-flex">
                    <v-col
                      cols="6"
                      md="6"
                      v-for="(item, index) in content"
                      :key="`item-${index}`"
                    >
                      <v-col cols="6">
                        <v-card-text>
                          <p>{{ item.id }}</p>
                          <p>my name is : {{ item.title }}</p>
                        </v-card-text></v-col
                      >
                    </v-col>
                  </v-row>
                </v-col>
              </v-row>

              <v-col cols="12" md="12" sm="12" class="d-flex">
                <v-col cols="6" md="6" sm="6">
                  <v-btn :disabled="isDisabledB" ref="back" medium elevation="" color="primary" @click="backpage()"
                    >Back</v-btn
                  >
                </v-col>
                <v-col cols="6" md="6" sm="6">
                  <v-btn :disabled="isDisabledN" ref="next" medium elevation="" color="secondary" @click="nextPage()"
                    >Next</v-btn
                  >
                </v-col>
              </v-col>
            </v-card>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
      </v-container>
   </v-main>
 </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: The user is using SFC files, try not to confuse him with some CDN imported files and `Vue.config` setup. Rather share him some codesandbox or just pure code.

Comment: Hey mate, thank you, will try to do that way. You think some comments around imports and config would clear confusion? cheers :)

Comment: The configuration part is already done on Nuxt, or should be done elsewhere and is not part of this question. As for imports, since the project would probably be generated with the Nuxt CLI, there is no need to talk about imports. We do suppose that the configuration is done well from the start.

Comment: Ok , got that, so pure vue.js, thanks gain, enjoy :)